# how I can change the value of the button depending on Spinner which takes the data from the database in Android?

Tags: android, database, button, spinner

I have a project to do android app, my app is about movies, I used the spinner to choose the name of the movie and there is a trailer button for each movie.
my question is how I can change the value of the button depending on the name of the movie.
I hope my question was clear

**MainActivity** class

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)

    TextView director;
    TextView year;
    TextView genre;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView rating;
    Button trailer;
    TextView movieStory;


    String[] movieNames = {"Test"}; 
    Spinner movieSpinner; 

    movieDB MovieDB; 

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        movieSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.moviespinner); 
        trailer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); 
        MovieDB = new movieDB(getApplicationContext()); 

        rating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rateText);
        director = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.director);
        year = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.year);
        genre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.genretext);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        movieStory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movieDetails);


        movieNames = MovieDB.getMovieNames(); 
        ArrayAdapter<String> movieAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_movie, movieNames);
        movieAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
        movieSpinner.setAdapter(movieAdapter); 



        movieSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       final int position, long arg3) {
                if (movieNames.length > position) {
                    director.setText(MovieDB.getDirector(movieNames[position]));
                    year.setText(MovieDB.getYear(movieNames[position]).toString());
                    genre.setText(MovieDB.getGenre(movieNames[position]));
                    imageView.setImageResource(MovieDB.getPhoto(movieNames[position]));
                    rating.setText(((Float) MovieDB.getRate(movieNames[position])).toString());
                    movieStory.setText(MovieDB.getStory(movieNames[position]));

// here is the trailer button
                        trailer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZjQROMAh_s"));
                            try {
                                MainActivity.this.startActivity(webIntent);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                            }
                        }
                    });



                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });


    }



}
```

the database

**movieDB** class

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class movieDB {

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

    public static final String KEY_MOVIE_NAME =
            "movie_name";
    public static final String KEY_DIRECTOR =
            "director_name";
    public static final String KEY_YEAR =
            "year";
    public static final String KEY_GENRE =
            "genre";
    public static final String KEY_PHOTO =
            "pic";
    public static final String KEY_RATE =
            "rate";
    public static final String KEY_STORY =
            "story";
    public static final String KEY_URL =
            "url";

    private Context context; 

    private ModuleDBOpenHelper moduleDBOpenHelper; 

    public movieDB(Context context) { 
        this.context = context;
        moduleDBOpenHelper = new ModuleDBOpenHelper(context, ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null,
                ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);

        // populate the database with some data in case it is empty
        if (getAll().length == 0) {

            this.addRow("1917", "Todd Phillips", 2019 ,"Crime, Drama, Thriller" , R.mipmap.mov_1917_foreground, 8.4f , context.getString(R.string.mov1917story),"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZjQROMAh_s");
            this.addRow("Avatar", "James Cameron", 2009, "Action, Adventure, Fantasy, Sci-Fi" , R.mipmap.avatar_foreground , 7.8f , context.getString(R.string.avatarstory),"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PSNL1qE6VY");
            this.addRow("Joker", "Todd Phillips", 2019,"Crime, Drama, Thriller" , R.mipmap.joker_foreground , 8.6f, context.getString(R.string.jokerstory),"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAGVQLHvwOY");
            this.addRow("Once Upon a Time in Hollywood", "Vladislav Kozlov", 2019,"Drama" , R.mipmap.hollywood_foreground , 7.7f , context.getString(R.string.hollywoodstory),"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELeMaP8EPAA");
            this.addRow("The Irishman", "Martin Scorsese", 2019,"Biography, Crime, Drama" , R.mipmap.irish_foreground , 8.0f , context.getString(R.string.irishmanstory),"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS3aHkkfuEI");
        }
    }

    public void addRow(String movieName, String director, int year, String genre , int pic , float rate , String story , String url) { 
        // Create a new row of values to insert.
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put(KEY_MOVIE_NAME, movieName);
        newValues.put(KEY_DIRECTOR, director);
        newValues.put(KEY_YEAR, year);

        newValues.put(KEY_GENRE, genre);
        newValues.put(KEY_PHOTO, pic);
        newValues.put(KEY_RATE, rate);
        newValues.put(KEY_STORY, story);
        newValues.put(KEY_URL, url);

        // Insert the row into your table
        SQLiteDatabase db = moduleDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, newValues);
    } 


    public String[] getAll() { 

        ArrayList<String> outputArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] result_columns = new String[]{

                KEY_MOVIE_NAME, KEY_DIRECTOR, KEY_YEAR , KEY_GENRE};

        String movieName;
        String directorName;
        int year;

        String genre;

        String where = null;
        String whereArgs[] = null;
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String order = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = moduleDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
                result_columns, where,
                whereArgs, groupBy, having, order);

        boolean result = cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (result) {
            movieName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MOVIE_NAME));
            directorName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DIRECTOR));
            year = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_YEAR));
            genre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_GENRE));
            outputArray.add(movieName + " "+ directorName +  year + " " + genre);
            result = cursor.moveToNext();

        }
        return outputArray.toArray(new String[outputArray.size()]);
    } 

    public String[] getMovieNames() { 

        ArrayList<String> outputArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] result_columns = new String[]{
                KEY_MOVIE_NAME};

        String movieName;

        String where = null;
        String whereArgs[] = null;
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String order = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = moduleDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
                result_columns, where,
                whereArgs, groupBy, having, order);
        //
        boolean result = cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (result) {
            movieName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MOVIE_NAME));

            outputArray.add(movieName);
            result = cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        return outputArray.toArray(new String[outputArray.size()]);
    } 

    public String geturl(String movieName) {
        String[] result_columns = new String[]{
                KEY_ID, KEY_URL};

        String where = KEY_MOVIE_NAME + "= ?";
        String whereArgs[] = {movieName};
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String order = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = moduleDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
                result_columns, where,
                whereArgs, groupBy, having, order);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnGenre = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_URL);
            return cursor.getString(columnGenre);
        } else return null;
    }

    public Integer getYear(String movieName) { 
        String[] result_columns = new String[]{
                KEY_ID, KEY_YEAR};


        String where = KEY_MOVIE_NAME + "= ?";
        String whereArgs[] = {movieName};
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String order = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = moduleDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
                result_columns, where,
                whereArgs, groupBy, having, order);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnYear = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_YEAR);
            return cursor.getInt(columnYear);
        } else return 0;
    } 

    public String getGenre(String movieName) { 
        String[] result_columns = new String[]{
                KEY_ID, KEY_GENRE};


        String where = KEY_MOVIE_NAME + "= ?";
        String whereArgs[] = {movieName};
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String order = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = moduleDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
                result_columns, where,
                whereArgs, groupBy, having, order);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnGenre = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_GENRE);
            return cursor.getString(columnGenre);
        } else return null;
    }

    public String getStory(String movieName) {
        String[] result_columns = new String[]{
                KEY_ID, KEY_STORY};


        String where = KEY_MOVIE_NAME + "= ?";
        String whereArgs[] = {movieName};
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String order = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = moduleDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
                result_columns, where,
                whereArgs, groupBy, having, order);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnStory = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_STORY);
            return cursor.getString(columnStory);
        } else return null;
    }

    public Integer getPhoto(String movieName) {
        String[] result_columns = new String[]{
                KEY_ID, KEY_PHOTO};


        String where = KEY_MOVIE_NAME + "= ?";
        String whereArgs[] = {movieName};
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String order = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = moduleDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
                result_columns, where,
                whereArgs, groupBy, having, order);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnPhoto = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHOTO);
            return cursor.getInt(columnPhoto);
        } else return 0;
    }


    public float getRate(String movieName) {
        String[] result_columns = new String[]{
                KEY_ID, KEY_RATE};


        String where = KEY_MOVIE_NAME + "= ?";
        String whereArgs[] = {movieName};
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String order = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = moduleDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
                result_columns, where,
                whereArgs, groupBy, having, order);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnRate = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_RATE);
            return cursor.getFloat(columnRate);
        } else return 0;
    }

    public String getDirector(String movieName) { 
        String[] result_columns = new String[]{
                KEY_ID, KEY_DIRECTOR};


        String where = KEY_MOVIE_NAME + "= ?";
        String whereArgs[] = {movieName};
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String order = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = moduleDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ModuleDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
                result_columns, where,
                whereArgs, groupBy, having, order);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnDirector = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DIRECTOR);
            return cursor.getString(columnDirector);
        } else return null;
    } 

    private static class ModuleDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Movies";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // SQL Statement to create a new database.
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " +
                DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID +
                " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                KEY_MOVIE_NAME + " text not null, " +
                KEY_DIRECTOR + " text , " +
                KEY_YEAR + " int , " +
                KEY_GENRE + " text , " +
                KEY_PHOTO + " int , " +
                KEY_RATE + " float , " +
                KEY_STORY + " text , " +
                KEY_URL + " text );";

        public ModuleDBOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
                                  SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }



        // Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
        // to create a new one.
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        // Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that
        // the version of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to
        // the current version.
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                              int newVersion) {
            // Log the version upgrade.
            Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +
                    oldVersion + " to " +
                    newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

            // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new
            // version. Multiple previous versions can be handled by
            // comparing oldVersion and newVersion values.

            // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            // Create a new one.
            onCreate(db);
        }
    } 


}
```

**XML Layout**
activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/moviespinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/directorcontainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/moviespinner">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/directorHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/director"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/director"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/directorHeading"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/yearcontainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/directorcontainer"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/directorcontainer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/directorcontainer"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yearHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/year"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/yearHeading"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/genrecontainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/directorcontainer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/yearcontainer"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/yearcontainer">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genreHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/genre"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genretext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/genreHeading"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/genrecontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="661dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="147dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/thumb"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Inset"
                android:layout_width="98dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/trailer" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="34dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="34dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/star"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/rateText"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/rate10"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/_10" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="13dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movieDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test_URL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**XML Layout** list_movie.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

[**[Image]** the appearance of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfCks.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
trailer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
          Uri.parse(MovieDB.geturl(movieNames[position])));
      try {
         MainActivity.this.startActivity(webIntent);
      } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
      }
   }
});
```